# JavaFX 1.8.0_192 - Menu items leaving behind background box

Tags: javafx, menu, javafx-8

[image: Menu with left behind background box] 
Our customers have reported that the menu item background boxes do not clear in the JavaFX client being used (after a week or so of use) - see photo above.

If the menu items are clicked after this has occurred, they display and function properly, however the background boxes stay and will not clear.

We have reproduced this using a soak test (using xdotool to simulate repeated mouse use), but there appear to be no errors reported in the log files.

We have also ran this soak test using a *Java 7* version and this behaviour does NOT occur.

The menu should look like this in normal behaviour: 
 [image: Normal menu]

We are using the latest version of Java 8.

Any ideas welcome, thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: That's not easy - it's a big application - which is wired up by Spring.  This appears to be a javaFX bug, wondered if anyone had encountered this before ? You're right though, now we've managed to reproduce this I should try to minimise it ...
Although - it takes about 18 hours to reproduce in our soak test as well !

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I have never seen this... Hopefully you'll get some help, upvoted.

Comment: Thanks - I'll need to streamline the app for the soak test first ... presently doing this

Comment: This looks more like a Graphics issue rather than a java issue. If you create a simple application with only a menu and some menu items do you still have the same result?

Comment: Um...yeah - a JavaFX graphics issue?  Is that what you meant?